# How to trim the time from the timestamp using php

Tags: php, mysql

I used timestamp to my table . 2012-07-30 10:12:39 is the format of time in my mysql records.How to to trim the time and display only date. in php page ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$mysqlDateTime = "2012-07-30 10:12:39";
```

If you just need the date from that, you can use something like this (easy) one:

```
list($date, $time) = explode(" ", $mysqlDateTime);
echo $date;
```

However, you may use also something like this:

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($mysqlDateTime));
```

**EDIT**

The solution of [donald123](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11724466/246051) may also be interesting for you.

Answer (score 2):

or in your sql-query

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(YOUR_TIME_FIELD,'%Y-%m-%d') as datefield
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 1):

Only in php?

```
//get value from database
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `datetime` FROM `table`");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$date = date_create($row[0]);

//output
echo date_format($date, 'd/m/y');
#output: 30/07/2012
```

Using MySql:

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(`datetime`,'%d-%m-%Y') as formattedDate FROM table
```